# Multiple possible interpreters in a shebang?

Tags: scripts, environment-variables, nodejs

Trying to learn me some nodejs, I installed npm and the [learnyounode](https://npmjs.org/package/learnyounode) module. Unfortunately, **learnyounode** tries to execute `#!/usr/bin/env node` and not `#!/usr/bin/env nodejs` -- as we have it setup in Ubuntu.

I've been looking, but I can't seem to find a way to have a *fallback shebang*. I know users can always link `/usr/bin/nodejs` to `/usr/bin/node`, but it'd be nice if there was a more elegant way to write runnable node scripts, regardless of if the interpreter was named  **node** or **nodejs**.

Answer (score 1):

In the `~/.profile` file, there is a piece of code that adds `$HOME/bin` to your PATH. You can use this feature to make "node" link to "nodejs":

```
mkdir ~/bin
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs ~/bin/node
```

You may have to re-login if your `$HOME/bin` directory did not exist before. You could also skip the shebang line and specify the interpreter directly:

```
nodejs learnyounode.js
```